# Decode this for the right answer

Tags: cipher

**ABABAAABAAAABAABAABAABABBAABAAAAAAABAAAAABAAAAABBAAABBBBAABAAAAAAABBAAAABBAABABAAABAA**

This an encrypted text. You need to decrypt it and encrypt it again to get the right answer.

Comment: Up, Up, Down, Down, Left, Right, Left, Right, B, A, Start...

Comment: (Why is the accepted answer accepted? It doesn’t seem to be compete, based on the problem specification...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strange... an incomplete answer was accepted.  Here's the completion:

As @hexomino found the decrypted message is:

> LEET ME A RIGHT ANGLE

The message was to be re-encrypted into:

> LEET

So the correct answer is:

> 4 r16H7 4N613

Answer (score 5):

It seems to say

> LEET ME A RIGHT ANGLE

This looks like a

> [Baconian cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher)

So let us

> Break it up into groups of 5.
>  ABABA AABAA AABAA BAABA ABABB AABAA AAAAA BAAAA ABAAA AABBA AABBB BAABA AAAAA ABBAA AABBA ABABA AABAA
>  which when translated, using the table provided in the link, becomes
>  LEETMEARIGHTANGLE
>  and adding spaces
>  LEET ME A RIGHT ANGLE

Perhaps there is a typo?

> Could be LEFT ME A RIGHT ANGLE

Comment: You have decrypted it, but you have not encrypted it again.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Ah, I missed that bit, will have to think on it.